# I'd better vs I better

Tags: grammar

English is not my native language, so I'm wondering, should I say:

> I'd better go away now.

or:

> I better go away now.

or even (I think I've heard this one):

> I better go now.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What makes you think that any of those are right or wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Opinions are varied, but Fowler probably sums up the situation best (the following, tidied, from [The Grammarphobia Blog](http://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2013/03/had-better.html) ):

> Using “better” by itself is fine except in formal English. “In a wide
>   range of informal circumstances (but never in formal contexts) the had
>   or ’d can be dispensed with,” Fowler’s says.
>
> Merriam-Webster’s Dictionary of English Usage calls “had better” a
>   standard English idiom and agrees with Fowler’s that “better,” when
>   used alone in this sense, “is not found in very formal surroundings.”
>
> The Oxford English Dictionary’s earliest citation for the construction
>   without “had” is from a pseudonymous letter to a newspaper by “Major
>   Jack Downing”:
>
> “My clothes had got so shabby, I thought I better hire out a few days
>   and get slicked up a little.” (The letter was published in a book in
>   1834 but was written in 1831.)
>
> The OED says the abbreviated usage originated in the US, and labels it
>   a colloquialism. But Merriam-Webster’s Collegiate Dictionary (11th
>   ed.) lists it without reservations.
>
> The Merriam-Webster’s editors give the example “you better hurry,” and
>   says “better” in this sense is a “verbal auxiliary.”
>
> It should be noted that even the full phrase, “had better,” was
>   criticized by some in the 19th century on the ground that it was
>   illogical and couldn’t be parsed: an 1897 issue of the Ohio Educational Monthly 
>   says many teachers found “had better” and other idioms “very difficult
>   to dispose of grammatically.”

Comment: *You better watch out, /
 You better not cry, /
 You better not pout, /
 I'm telling you why: 
/ Santa Claus is coming to town!*

Comment: Obviously a more highly respected authority than most whose names we drop here. However, when it comes to choosing the lyrics, Bruce Springsteen and John Michael Montgomery seem to be more prescriptivist.