# You better vs. You have better

Tags: word-choice, verbs, tenses

Which one is correct?

You **better** visit your family.

You **have better** visit your family.

You **had better** visit your family.

Comment: Related: [I'd better vs I better](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/236948/id-better-vs-i-better)

Answer (score 5):

"You have better" is not English.

"You had better" is normal English, meaning "you ought to"; it is usually reduced in speech to "You'd better".

"You better" is a common colloquial form of "You'd better": many people regard it as "wrong", and would not accept it in writing.

Comment: Why we use "had" for the present and the future? Why not use "have"?

Comment: It's neither present nor future: it's a suggestion.

Comment: Because that's what English does. (As with most "why" questions, that is the whole of the answer).